# Cumulative Returns

Tags: julia

In R we can do:

```
cum.ret <- cumprod(1 + df$rets) - 1
```

I want to do the same thing with Julia here is some dummy data:

```
# Dummy Data
df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = 10*rand(10), Close = 10 * rand(10))

# Calculate Returns 
Close = df[:Close]
Close = convert(Array, Close)
df[:Close_Rets] = [NaN; (Close[2:end] ./ Close[1:(end-1)] - 1)] 

# Calculate Cumulative Returns 
df[:Cum_Ret] = cumprod(((1 .+ df[:Close_Rets])-1),2)
```

With the output:

```
julia> head(df)
6×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a │ b       │ Close    │ Close_Rets │ Cum_Ret   │
├─────┼───┼─────────┼──────────┼────────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 6.15507 │ 3.6363   │ NaN        │ NaN       │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 7.73259 │ 0.98378  │ -0.729456  │ -0.729456 │
│ 3   │ 3 │ 3.64926 │ 7.94633  │ 7.07735    │ 7.07735   │
│ 4   │ 4 │ 5.15762 │ 0.744905 │ -0.906258  │ -0.906258 │
│ 5   │ 5 │ 9.49532 │ 8.51811  │ 10.4352    │ 10.4352   │
│ 6   │ 6 │ 6.14604 │ 5.02165  │ -0.410473  │ -0.410473 │
```

Anyway to make this work?

Comment: `[NaN; cumprod(1+df[2:end, :Close_Rets])-1]`.